# React Native - Make a component accept a view as prop and display it

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am very much new to React Native.

In my project, I have a requirement that looks like this.

I have a `Component` called `BaseComponent` that accepts a View as a prop and display it inside a touchable highlight in its render method.

I am using this `BaseComponent` in my `CustomComponent` by passing a view as a prop. This `View` which is being passed is returned from a function called `getView()`. But it is showing me a blank screen.

```
// BaseComponent.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

export default class BaseComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress= { this.onPress.bind(this) } >

          <View>
            {
              this.props.contentView
            }
          </View>

      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

--

```
// CustomComponent.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent'

export default class CustomComponent extends Component {

  getView() {
    return(
      <Text> Hello { this.props.name }! </Text>
    )
  }

  render() {
    <BaseComponent contentView={ this.getView.bind(this) }>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just edit your code like:

```
// BaseComponent.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableHighlight, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class BaseComponent extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={null}>

         <View>
           <Text> hello </Text>
         </View>

      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

And ...

```
// CustomComponent.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';

export default class routerFlax extends Component {
  getView() {
    return <Text> Hello {this.props.name}! </Text>;
  }

  render() {
    return <BaseComponent contentView={this.getView.bind(this)} />;
  }
}
```

in my emulator the code showing like :

[image]

The problem is you pass the props null and you don't return component render. So the result is blank.

*Edit*#1

based on your comment about your problem, i think you just change:

```
<BaseComponent contentView={this.getView.bind(this)} />;
```

To

```
<BaseComponent contentView={this.getView()} />;
```

in my emulator the code showing like :

[image: new answer]

I hope my answer helping you.. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! but unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. What I need is, I should be able to pass a view as a prop to the BaseComponent and make it render inside its return method. This answer is not helping to fix that problem. :(

Comment: oh.. sorry.. i edit my answer. i hope that answer your question. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This did work. Weird thing is that I have tried this before. But did not work for some reason. But this time it did work! :)